# Can I define optional packages in setuptools?

Tags: python, setuptools

Currently one of my packages requires a JSON parser/encoder, and is designed to use `simplejson` if available falling back to the `json` module (in the standard library) if necessary (as benchmarks show `simplejson` is faster).

However, recently it's been hit or miss as to whether `simplejson` will install when using `zc.buildout` - something with the move to github, I believe. Which got me wondering; is it possible to define optional packages in my `setup.py` file which, if unavailable, won't stop the installation of my package?

Answer (score 23):

## optional packages at installation time.

I am assuming you are talking about your `setup.py` script.
You could change it to have:

```
# mypackage/setup.py

extras = {
   'with_simplejson': ['simplejson>=3.5.3']
}

setup(
    ...
    extras_require=extras,
    ...)
```

then you can do either of:

- `pip install mypackage`,
- `pip install mypackage[with_simplejson]`

with the latter installing `simplejson>=3.5.3`.

Instead of trying to install everything and fallback to a known good version,
you would want to install the subset of packages you know work.

## optional packages at execution time.

Once you have two different sets of packages that could be installed, you need
to make sure you can use them if they are available. E.g. for your `json` import:

```
try:
    # helpful comment saying this should be faster.
    import simplejson as json
except ImportError:
    import json
```

Another more complex example:

```
try:
    # xml is dangerous
    from defusedxml.cElementTree import parse
except ImportError:
    try:
        # cElementTree is not available in older python
        from xml.cElementTree import parse
    except ImportError:
        from xml.ElementTree import parse
```

But you can also find this pattern in some packages:

```
try:
    optional_package = None
    import optional.package as optional_package
except ImportError:
    pass

...

if optional_package:
    # do addtional behavior
```

Comment: Very useful discussion of the practical in-code implications of optional requirements - another way is to do some imports inside functions, and raise exceptions from there if the specific code path is used at all (suggesting what to install in error messages).

Answer (score -2):

AFAIK there is no way to define an optional package and there would be no use to do so. What do you expect when you define an optional package? That it is installed when it is not yet available? (that would somehow make it mandatory)

No, IMHO the correct way to address this is in your imports where you want to use the package. E.g:

```
try:
    from somespecialpackage import someapi as myapi
except ImportError:
    from basepackage import theapi as myapi
```

This of course requires that the two APIs are compatible, but this is the case with `simplejson` and the standard library `json` package.

Comment: Optional would mean that if the package fails to install, the install can complete unimpeded.

Comment: Okay, but if you don't *vitaly rely* on a package, why put it in the *required packages* anyway? I simply don't get the point.

Comment: I don't want to put it into the `required` list; that's what I'm asking - is there another option so I can have it included if available, but ignored if not?

Comment: Because there may be C optimized libraries that mimic behavior and are difficult to build on certain platforms. This helps with development, particularly if you are on non *nix based OSes.